# Get YouTube audio stream on-the-fly

Tags: php, audio, youtube, stream, mp3

I am trying to get an audio stream (in mp3 format with fixed quality) from a YouTube video in PHP.

Notice that I cannot use FFMPEG and also i do not want to save the mp3 on my server, but I need only the audio stream (on the fly use).

Do you have any code or script? I have used many, but the half needs FFMPEG and the other saves the mp3 file in the server.

My plan is to hit on the browser:

```
http://host.com/process.php?url=<youtubeurl>
```

and get the audio stream in the page in variable that creating every time

```
&stream = ......;
```

Comment: The goal is to download only the audio stream in variable, then i send it to an app for edit! Now i use an extrenal site to get the audio stream but i just host the procces in my server and on the fly!

Comment: Notice that i learn something very usefull beside my university! The videos has the audio inside 'tags' so we can export the audio stream without rencode it! So we need a program do that which will not be the ffmpeg but a smaller and lighter program! Have an seen something like this in php?

Comment: Have you tried to implement and adapt on of the [official code samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not PHP, but we've open sourced a simple all-in-one node.js/CoffeeScript web app that can download a YouTube videos from a URL and then convert the video into an MP3 using ffmpeg.

[github](https://github.com/themgt/yt2mp3) / [demo](http://yt2mp3-demo.pogoapp.io/play?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2RgYkkK7OM) / [blog](http://www.pogoapp.com/blog/posts/youtube-mp3-with-node-js-and-ffmpeg)

Comment: Thanks for your responce but as said i cant use FFMPEG as server not allowed on shared hosting plan! So i am looking for for other solution... if anyone can know about this it would be very helpfull...

Comment: The demo is not working: Cannot GET /play?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2RgYkkK7OM